# Displaying Column Headers As Dates Telerik Rad Grid

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

Normally I would have code to post. However, I'm not sure where to start on this one. Maybe I am incorrect but this request is a little different than most (from clients). So, they are needing a new feature added to their page. They want to be able to run a report which shows all employees total hours for a given set of weeks. They will use a DatePicker to select a start date and another to select and end date. Then, click a button to run the report. This report will have the employee name as the first column and then each column after that will have a header which is a date. So if they selected 8-5-2017 and 8-19-2017 the column headers will be 8-5-2017| 8-12-2017| 8-19-2017. Underneath those columns will be the total hours each employee worked for that given week.

I've attached an image of what I am needing to do. Hopefully this will provide additional clarification.[image: sample display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar situation and managed to solve it by using a `DataTable` that contained my data. A simple way to fill your `DataTable` would be by creating a stored procedure.

In my example I'll simply do it for every day between 2 given dates, you should be able to change this code to have it work for once every 7 days, starting on a monday/sunday, depending on what your requirement is. If you need help with that as well, just leave a comment and I'll see what I can do if I find some time.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DayTableType] AS TABLE(
    [Datum] [date] NOT NULL,
    [DayCol] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @d1 datetime, @d2 datetime
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET DATEFIRST 1;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @StartDate date = CONVERT(date, @d1);
DECLARE @EndDate date = CONVERT(date, @d2);


DECLARE @Days dbo.DayTableType;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @StartDate AS Datum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(day,1,Datum) as Datum
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(day,1,Datum) <=  @EndDate
)
INSERT INTO @Days
SELECT cte.Datum, DATEPART(DAY, cte.Datum)
FROM cte
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
DECLARE @dPivot NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @dPivot = ''
SELECT @dPivot = @dPivot + '[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),d.Datum,3) + '],' FROM @Days d
SELECT @dPivot = SUBSTRING(@dPivot,1,LEN(@dPivot)-1)

DECLARE @SQLSTR NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQLSTR =
    'SELECT p.EmployeeId
        ,p.LastName
        ,p.FirstName
        ,'+ @dPivot + '
    FROM (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),d.Datum,3) AS DayCol
            ,e.EmployeeId
            ,e.LastName
            ,e.FirstName
            ,ISNULL((SELECT SUM(w.WorkedHours) FROM dbo.[EmployeeWorkDateTable] w
                    WHERE w.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId AND CONVERT(DATE, w.WorkDate) = CONVERT(DATE, d.Datum)),0) AS DayInfo
        FROM @Days d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[EmployeeTable] e ON e.IsActive = 1
    ) t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(t.DayInfo) 
        FOR t.DayCol IN (' + @dPivot + ')
        ) AS p
    ORDER BY p.LastName'

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLSTR, N'@Days DayTableType READONLY, @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE', @Days, @StartDate, @EndDate

END
```

This should return a `DataTable` that looks a lot like what you've posted in your screenshot.
To have this display correctly into your `GridView` you have need to first get this in your ViewModel as followed:

```
private DataTable _myDataTable;
public DataTable MyDataTable
{
    get { return _myDataTable; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _myDataTable, value); }
}



public void FillMyDataTable(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", conn) { CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", startDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", endDate);

        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        MyDataTable = ds.Tables[0];
    }       
}
```

Now you should simply bind your `GridView` itemsource to the `DefaultView` property of your `DataTable` and have the `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, you can edit the  column names and other stuff even more by writing your custom emplementation of `AutoGeneratingColumn`

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="MyGridView" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable.DefaultView}"
    AutoGeneratingColumn="MyGridView_OnAutoGeneratingColumn">
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

I hope this helps you out with your problem. Feel free to leave a comment if you have any more questions.

Comment: That was a very solid solution. I have to say that answer is the best I've received for the majority of the questions asked. I'm sorry I didn't respond sooner to accept this solution. Things have been crazy.